# How to render a partial view by name within a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages, partial-views

I am trying to implement something like Ruby on Rail's [`ActionDispatch::Flash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) to pass messages to the next page request. The approach that I want to take is to store a pair of (partial view name, model object) in the session context and render it in the master page when rendering the request to display the flash message.

Inside my `HttpApplication` subclass I now have:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public class FlashStuff
    {
        private string flashViewName;
        private object model;

        public FlashStuff(string flashViewName, object model)
        {
            this.flashViewName = flashViewName;
            this.model = model;
        }

        public string FlashViewName
        {
            get { return flashViewName; }
        }

        public object Model
        {
            get { return model; }
        }
    }

    internal static void Flash(string flashViewName, object model)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("flash", new FlashStuff(flashViewName, model));
    }

    //...
 }
```

I also have a `BookmarkController` with an action to add a bookmark:

```
[HandleError]
public class BookmarkController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Bookmark_AddModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //...

            Global.Flash("BookmarkAddedFlash", model);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Bookmark");
        }

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

In my master page I now want something like:

```
        <% var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
           if (session["flash"] != null)
           {
               var flashStuff = (MyApp.Web.Global.FlashStuff)session["flash"]; %>
               <div><!-- render in here --></div>
        <%     session.Remove("flash");
           } %>
```

to render the partial view that was specified by name when Global#Flash was called.

I want to use a view for the flash message instead of saving the message as a `string` in the session context because I want to include the URL in the message:

```
<%-- BookmarkAddedFlash.ascx --%>
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Web.Models.Bookmark_AddModel>" %>
<%: Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Url) %> was successfully bookmarked.
```

And I only want to render the view when the subsequent request is made;  i.e. one request sets the flash message and the subsequent request renders it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of RoR's Flash object in ASP.NET MVC is called [`TempData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx).

```
public ActionResult Action1()
{
    TempData["message"] = "some message";
    return RedirectToAction("action2");
}

public ActionResult Action2()
{
    var message = TempData["message"] as string;
    return View();
}
```

or use it directly in the `Action2` view:

```
<div><%: TempData["message"] %></div>
```

Internally `TempData` uses the Session object to store data but it is automatically invalidated after one redirect. So what you are trying to implement already exists.

Comment: `TempData` appears to be what I am looking for to store the data. However, I would like to render a partial view in the master page given the name of the partial view. How do I do that?

Comment: You could use `<% Html.RenderPartial("NameOfYourPartialView"); %>` or by providing the full path `<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/Foo.ascx"); %>`. Another thing you may take a look is child action with Html.Action and Html.RenderAction helpers. Phil Haack wrote a nice blog post about them: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I fully understand. I recently implemented a 'growl' infrastructure that I used an an asp.net mvc project. It sounds similar in some respects. Here is a link to that implementation:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/08/making-the-web-growl-using-jquery/

Hope this helps.

Bob